# Computation of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}(xy)^{k}[\cos n(x-y)-\cos n(x+y)] \, dx \, dy$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, integration, fourier-series

Find the value
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}(xy)^{k}[\cos n(x-y)-\cos n(x+y)] \, dx \, dy,\qquad k\in N^{+}$$

My idea:
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}(xy)^{k}[\cos n(x-y) -\cos n(x+y)] \, dx \, dy\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{\pi}x^k\sin(nx) \, dx\right)^2
\end{align}

Then we use $$
\sin{nx}=\dfrac{e^{inx}-e^{-inx}}{2i}$$
where $i=\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you, can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

The series converges by Parseval's theorem, which also tells us its value. Begin with 
$$x^k = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \sin nx\quad \text{where } \ b_n=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi x^k \sin nx\,dx\tag1$$
Since $\sqrt{2/\pi}\sin nx$ are orthonormal functions on $[0,\pi]$, it follows that 
$$\sum \frac{\pi}2 b_n^2 = \int_0^\pi x^{2k}\,dx = \frac{\pi^{2k+1}}{2k+1} \tag2 $$
Hence, 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\int_0^\pi x^k \sin nx\,dx\right)^2 = \frac{\pi^{2k+2}}{4k+2}\tag3$$